# iOS without opening FBDialog i need to share my params

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4

I'm using Facebook native API for sharing here i need to share my params without opening the FBDialog, like say i have a share button and a textField, inside textField user will enter text and as soon as he clicks share whatever the text inside textField has to share on his wall without opening FBDialog.(Similiar to SoundTracking App)
How can i accomplish this?
Any help is appereciated in advance.Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

by doing lots of research finally i got the solution for my own question,
store ur textview text inside an NSString as below,

```
NSString *shareTxt = TextView.text;
```

In Share button action add snippet below,

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"YourFacebookAppID",@"api_key", shareTxt,@"message",nil]; 

        [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```